# value of i increased but i didnt increment it

Tags: javascript

in this piece of code value of i has increased , and i dont know why.
in this i am calling getBlock which returns a promise and after that i call another getBlock to get the next block. but in between the value of i increases .

plz help

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.getBlockHeight().then((height)=>{
          let errorLog = [];
          for(var i=0;i <height;i++){
               self.validateBlock(i).then((valid)=>{
                    if(!valid){errorLog.push(i)}
               })

               self.getBlock(i).then((block)=>{ //here i is 0
                     console.log(i)             //here i is 1 
                 self.getBlock(i+1).then((previousblock)=>{
                   // console.log(i);
                   let blockHash = block.hash;
                   // console.log(block)
                   let previousBlockHash = previousblock.previousHash;
                   // console.log(previousblock);
                   if(!(blockHash == previousBlockHash)){
                     errorLog.push(i)
                   }

                 })
               })

          }

    })

  });
```

}

Comment: The usage of `then()` suggest asynchronous logic.  The `i` variable is not block scoped.

Comment: Where is the `getBlock()` function defined?

Comment: @Taplar thnx i solved this by making a new promise for both self.getBlock and then resolving them together with Promise.all() . I think asynchronicity was the problem. once again thnx